# preg_replace - replace certain character

Tags: php, preg-replace

i want : He had XXX to have had it. Or : He had had to have XXX it.

```
$string = "He had had to have had it.";
echo preg_replace('/had/', 'XXX', $string, 1);
```

output :

> He XXX had to have had it.

in the case of, 'had' is replaced is the first.

I want to use the second and third. not reading from the right or left, what "preg_replace" can do it ?

Comment: using preg_replace_callback() you could keep a counter of the found occurrences to determine whether to simply replace with itself or with your XXX value

Comment: @ivanichi... What is exact input and expected output you want, give details in brief.

Comment: @Navnath, i want, He XXX had to have had it OR He had XXX to have had it OR He had had to have XXX it, syntax should not be reading from the right or left, because it must be ensured where the sequence is replaced from the same word

Comment: @ivanichi, You mean multiple result statements of one statement like permutation ? replace only one word with multiple possibilities ? is it so

Comment: @Navnath, replace words in a certain order, if I had the same 5 words, then I can easily replace the third or fourth word, etc

Comment: @MarkBaker and Navnath, thanks for your help, Your code is the solution of my question, problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "He had had to have had it.";
$replace = 'XXX';
$counter = 0;  // Initialise counter
$entry = 2;    // The "found" occurrence to replace (starting from 1)

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/had/',
    function ($matches) use ($replace, &$counter, $entry) {
        return (++$counter == $entry) ? $replace : $matches[0];
    },
    $string
);
```

Comment: @mark,  i've tried your syntax but error unexpected T_FUNCTION, Can you fix to try again ? thanks.

Comment: So what version of PHP are you using? This requires at least 5.3.0, though you should be using at least that version anyway

Comment: @MarkBaker, what do you mean, The "found" occurrence to replace (starting from 1), this is my output if i make $entry = 1; He XXX XXX to have XXX it. and I did not find how to make output : He had XXX to have had it. Or : He had had to have XXX it Or He XXX had to have had it , but thanks, there may be other ideas.

Comment: This code, as it stands, will replace one (and only one) occurrence of `had` with `XXX`. $entry specifies which occurrence, the 1st, 2nd or 3rd. To replace the 3rd, giving you `He had had to have XXX it.`, you would set $entry to a value of 3. To replace the 2nd, giving you `He had XXX to have had it.`, you would set $entry to a value of 2. To replace the 2nd, giving you `He XXX had to have had it.`, you would set $entry to a value of 1. The code works perfectly for me. Please make sure you have typed/copied it correctly.

Comment: @MarkBaker, Thank you very much Mark, i'm sorry, I made ​​a mistake copy, your code was absolutely perfect, i think this is the solution, the problem has been resolved, thanks to your help. you really helped me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  <?php
function my_replace($srch, $replace, $subject, $skip=1){
    $subject = explode($srch, $subject.' ', $skip+1);
    $subject[$skip] = str_replace($srch, $replace, $subject[$skip]);
    while (($tmp = array_pop($subject)) == '');
    $subject[]=$tmp;
    return implode($srch, $subject);
}
$test ="He had had to have had it.";;
echo my_replace('had', 'xxx', $test);
echo "<br />\n";
echo my_replace('had', 'xxx', $test, 2);
?>
```

Look at [CodeFiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/neAn9Z)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Solution**

```
function generate_patterns($string, $find, $replace) {

// Make single statement
// Replace whitespace characters with a single space
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);

// Count no of patterns
$count = substr_count($string, $find);

// Array of result patterns
$solutionArray = array();

// Require for substr_replace
$findLength = strlen($find);

// Hold index for next replacement
$lastIndex = -1;

  // Generate all patterns
  for ( $i = 0; $i < $count ; $i++ ) {

    // Find next word index
    $lastIndex = strpos($string, $find, $lastIndex+1);

    array_push( $solutionArray , substr_replace($string, $replace, $lastIndex, $findLength));
  }

return $solutionArray;
}

$string = "He had had to have had it.";

$find = "had";
$replace = "yz";

$solutionArray = generate_patterns($string, $find, $replace);

print_r ($solutionArray);
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => He yz had to have had it.
    [1] => He had yz to have had it.
    [2] => He had had to have yz it.
)
```

**I manage this code try to optimize it.**

Comment: it's okay, but thank you for giving an answer, maybe some other people would need this answer. yup, this syntax replace all but not first one

Comment: @ivanichi..If you want to replace only first string then your code is working, can you tell me what you want ?

Comment: @ivanichi... You say's - I want to use the second and third. not reading from the right or left, what "preg_replace" can do it ? Means what ?

Comment: i want, He XXX had to have had it OR He had XXX to have had it OR He had had to have XXX it, syntax should not be reading from the right or left, because it must be ensured where the sequence is replaced from the same word (replace words in a certain order, if I had the same 5 words, then I can easily replace the third word, etc)

Comment: my code works, but only for this output : He XXX had to have had it

Comment: @ivanichi...Check my new solution.

Comment: hi.. thank you very much, idea and your code is correct, i think this is the solution, the problem has been resolved, thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not going to win any concours d'elegance with this, but very short:

```
$string = "He had had to have had it.";
echo strrev(preg_replace('/dah/', 'XXX', strrev($string), 1));
```

Comment: it's okay, but thank you for giving an answer, maybe some other people would need this answer